# How to run sql scripts serially in bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, db2

I have 2 DB2 sql scripts that I need to run. I have tried to put both of them in bash script and execute them.

here is script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
db2 -tf firstscript.sql;
db2 -tf secondscript.sql;
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist. 
>   SQLSTATE=08003

But I have made sure that the database connection already exists.

I think that the commands inside the sql scripts are not executed sequentially.
Because when I run each command individually, there is no error.
Also, when I run both the commands inline i.e. `db2 -tf firstscript.sql;db2 -tf firstscript.sql`, even then the code works.

I thought that it could have something to do with `#!/bin/bash`, so I removed it from the script.sh file and then executed it. Even then, it returned the same error.

What would be the possible problem and its solution?

Comment: If you run the above script, it will executed sequentially. If they're works when entered directly, try the next: `source myscript.sh`. If it will work, the problem is probably in some bash variable, what isn't exported. If will not work, haven't idea. Youre running bash as your command line shell? What prints the `ps -p $$` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a establish connection, it is hold in your current environment. When you call a bash script, it will create a subshell, and that will not have any connection.

In order to solve this problem, you need to reuse the current environment by sourcing the script (as @jm666 said):

```
. ./script.sh
```

Make sure about the dot followed by a space before the scriptname.

```
db2 connect to sample
. ./script.sh
```

FYI, the commands inside the script will be executed sequentially, as you defined them.